# Как растянуть колонки DataGrid в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

[image: картинка]

У меня две колонки `DataGrid` имеют ширину длиной в текст, а как их растянуть эти две колонки на две колонки в `Grid`?

Скрытая часть кода это 2 строки и 5 колонок без атрибутов у Grid.

Comment: добавь код в виде текста.

Comment: @codename0082016 там стандартно 2 строки и 5 колонок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выставлять ширину каждой колонки вручную:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prop1" Binding="{Binding Prop1}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prop2" Binding="{Binding Prop2}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>            
</DataGrid>
```

Также можно через стили:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="*"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Так а онр будет "резиновым"?

Comment: @kot_mapku3, так колонки растянуться на всю ширину DataGrid

Comment: Ты гений, парень :D